# grep command in bash scripting

Tags: script, grep

```
grepstr()
{
 grep "$1 $2" $TMP/"ORACLE_SID"_dbmode.txt > /dev/null 2>$1
}
```

1. What is the meaning of the above command?
2. What are `$1` and `$2`? Why it is necessary?
3. Is there any alternatives for using `$1` and `$2`?

Answer (score 3):

Is that exactly what the code looks like?

As it is, it is a function that takes two arguments, let's say they're `arg1` and `arg2`.

Then it reads a file called `ORACLE_SID_dbmode.txt` and prints every line that contains `arg1 arg2` (joined together with a space in between), and saves the error messages in a file called `arg1`.

This is quite confusing, so I don't think this is the actual code.

I would imagine it is actually this:

```
grepstr()
{
    grep "$1" "$2" $TMP/"$ORACLE_SID"_dbmode.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Changes:

- `"$1 $2"` becomes `"$1" "$2"`
- `ORACLE_SID` becomes `$ORACLE_SID`
- `2>$1` becomes `2>&1`

If so, it could be used two ways:

```
grepstr options string_or_pattern
```

for example:

```
grepstr -i something
```

would make it print (see below) any lines in the file `"$ORACLE_SID"_dbmode.txt` that include the string `something`, `Something`, `SOMETHING`, etc.

`-i` means case insensitive and is just an example; any option could be used.

(Also, technically `something` is not a string, but a pattern, for example `[0-9]` would match any digit).

The second way is:

```
grepstr string_or_pattern filename
```

in which case it will print any lines matching string_or_pattern in `filename` or `"$ORACLE_SID"_dbmode.txt`.

That seems less likely, but it is possible, depending how the code is used.

It could also be called like this:

```
grepstr option1 option2
```

but that would read from standard input (e.g. the keyboard by default), and print any lines that contained `"$ORACLE_SID"_dbmode.txt`, which is almost certainly not what was intended, given `"$ORACLE_SID"_dbmode.txt` looks like a file name, not a string or pattern to match.

If my guess is right, the code isn't `>/dev/null 2>$1`, instead it's `>/dev/null 2>&1`, which means output and error messages are not printed.

`>/dev/null` means that grep's standard output (i.e. the matching lines) is being sent to `/dev/null`, which is a special file that the operating system just ignores.

`2>&1` after `>/dev/null` means that error messages go there too.

So if the output isn't important, `grepstr` is probably being called either like this:

```
if grepstr...
```

or like this:

```
grepstr...
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
```

to only execute some code if there was a match.

In answer to the other part of your question, yes, it could be changed to

```
grepstr()
{
    grep "$@" $TMP/"$ORACLE_SID"_dbmode.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

The `"$@"` expands to `"$1" "$2" "$3"...` (i.e. as many arguments as are provided).

I think that way would be better, because it would be more flexible.

On the other hand, if it does require two arguments for some reason I can't think of, then perhaps `"$1" "$2"` is what the author intended.

Answer (score 0):

`$1` and `$2` are parameters. Your snippet is defining function `grepstr`.

For example, running

```
grepstr first second
```

actually runs command

```
grep "first second" $TMP/"ORACLE_SID"_dbmode.txt
```

and redirects output to `/dev/null` (which is message sink, everything put there just disappears).

Basically, when you run script (or function), `$1`, `$2`, `$3` (etc.) are parameters you gave. You can test whether parameter is set with `-z`, for example `if [ -z $3 ]; then ...`.